# Python - Definição de path ST.PROJECT_ROOT = os.environ['PROJECT_ROOT']

Tags: python

Estou tentando rodar um [projeto de teste](https://github.com/StandOutstar/Pytest_Allure_Airtest_Demo),
mas sempre dá esse erro:

```
ImportError while loading conftest 'D:\_Automation\_Projects_automation\Automation_Poco_Pytest\Automation_runner\cases\conftest.py'.
..\conftest.py:16: in <module>
    ST.PROJECT_ROOT = os.environ['PROJECT_ROOT']
C:\Users\tf.dias\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\os.py:669: in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
E   KeyError: 'PROJECT_ROOT'
```

Eu havia colocado em `PROJECT_ROOT` o nome do projeto, mas não funcionou. Essa parte de configuração to tentando aprender agora. Ai estou tentando montar um projeto que use, Pytest, Python, com allure.

Comment: O Python está puxando esse valor das variáveis de ambiente. Você configurou de alguma forma essas variáveis no seu ambiente?

Comment: Sim, esta configurado, mas nao sei o porque de nao reconhecer